# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'displayVoiceState')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, typeerror

I am creating my bot on discord.js and I need help.
Like bot is working, but when I use `/play` command I get an error in the console.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'displayVoiceState')
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/LuzeNAI-v09/events/Guild/voiceStateUpdate.js:12:35)
    at Client.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at VoiceStateUpdate.handle (/home/runner/LuzeNAI-v09/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/VoiceStateUpdate.js:38:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as VOICE_STATE_UPDATE] (/home/runner/LuzeNAI-v09/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/VOICE_STATE_UPDATE.js:4:35)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/LuzeNAI-v09/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:352:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/LuzeNAI-v09/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:481:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/runner/LuzeNAI-v09/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:321:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/runner/LuzeNAI-v09/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/home/runner/LuzeNAI-v09/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:1178:20)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:384:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:85:21)
```

Code with voiceStateUpdate:

```
const { EmbedBuilder, PermissionsBitField, codeBlock } = require("discord.js");
const client = require("../../index");
const config = require("../../config/config.js");
const { QuickDB } = require("quick.db");
const db = new QuickDB();

module.exports = {
  name: "voiceStateUpdate",
};

client.on("voiceStateUpdate", async (client, oldState, newState) => {
  const display = client.config.displayVoiceState;

  if (newState.channelId === null) {
    if (display)
      console.log("--", newState.member.user.username, " left channel ");
  } else if (oldState.channelId === null) {
    if (display)
      console.log(
        "--",
        newState.member.user.username,
        " joined channel ",
        newState.channel.name
      );
  } else {
    if (display)
      console.log(
        "--",
        newState.member.user.username,
        " moved channel ",
        oldState.channel.name,
        " to ",
        newState.channel.name
      );

    if (!oldState.member.user.bot) {
      const queue = await client.player.getQueue(oldState.guild.id);
      const botChannelId = queue?.connection?.channel?.id;
      const oldStateId = oldState.channel.id;

      if (botChannelId === oldStateId) {
        if (oldState.channel.members.size <= 1) {
          client.player.deleteQueue(oldState.guild.id);
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The problem is I've got that error and I don't know why. In config.js I have `displayVoiceState` set to `false`. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

client is not an object. But displayVoiceState is a property of config object. try;

```
const display = config.displayVoiceState;
```

Comment: Okay, thanks! It solved my problem, but there is next one. Now it can't read "channelId" in " if (newState.channelId === null) { "

Comment: Well, there's a lot of confusion in the code, specially how you are handling the event "voiceStateUpdate". In the code, "voiceStateUpdate" is not an envent and "client" is not an event emitter either. I think you should go throught the logic again.

Comment: @Matuzh If you have a follow-up question that is unrelated to the problem/error asked in your post, then it should be a separate question. See [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions).